# How to convert this complex number to exponential form?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have $Z = {\frac{2+i}{2-i}}$. I need to write it in exponential form, i.e. $Z = r*e^{i{\phi}}$.

I simplified the given example to ${\frac{3 + 4i}{5}}$, i.e. $a={\frac{3}{5}}, b={\frac{4}{5}}$. Therefore, $r = 1$.

Then I calculate $cos({\phi}) = a / r = 3 / 5, sin({\phi})=b/r = 4/5$. How do I calculate ${\phi}$ from here?

The online [Complex Number Exponential Form](https://www.dcode.fr/complex-number-exponential-form) given ${\phi}=tan^{-1}({\frac{4}{3}})$.

Comment: It's done. There's nothing esle you can do after that.

Comment: How did the online calculator work then?

Comment: The phase is the $tan^{-1}(b/a)$

Comment: Also, notice that $\sin(\phi)=4/5$ and $\cos(\phi)=3/5$ means that $\tan(\phi)=\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\phi)}=\frac 4 5 \cdot \frac 5 3 = \frac 4 3$, so you hav ethe same answer. So $\phi = \operatorname{asin}(4/5)=\operatorname{acos}(3/5)$

Comment: @user3132457 Compare the online calculator's result to the result you get when you evaluate the arctangent function with your own calculator. The answer you got is an exact answer. There is no need to get a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos\phi=\frac{3}{5}\\ \sin\phi=\frac45$$
Divide the second by the first
$$\tan\phi=\frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}=\frac{4/5}{3/5}=\frac43$$Therefore $\phi=\arctan\frac43$